# Is it correct to intrigue me?

Tags: grammaticality

In conversation if someone pitches something to you but you're not entirely convinced, can you ask for more details by saying "intrigue me"?

Comment: That would be "(You mean to) intrigue me!" in an imperative, if not snarky, remark. Fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, there's nothing at all wrong with [imperative](http://www.englishlanguageguide.com/grammar/imperative.asp) *"Intrigue me"*, but it seems likely OP has misunderstood what the verb *to intrigue* actually means. From OED...

> *(transitive)* To excite the curiosity or interest of; to interest so as to puzzle or fascinate.

The meaning OP wants to convey is normally expressed by *"Convince me"*. But here's an example where it really *does* mean *"Do something to excite my interest"*...

> *(New York Magazine ["Lonely Hearts" column, 1985](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=z7gBAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA139&dq=%22you%20to%20intrigue%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ozimUfySNsmt0QXckIEQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22you%20to%20intrigue%20me%22&f=false))*
>    Passionate, Brilliant, Bizarre — Woman, 29.
>    I am quite wicked, beautiful and successful. I dare you to intrigue me.

Answer (score 1):

No. You are intrigued. The other person does not intrigue you.

You could rephrase it as:

> I am intrigued. Please tell me more.

But that wouldn't necessarily have anything to do with being convinced, more to do with your curiosity being aroused.

To correctly rephrase your sentence I would go with:

> Convince me.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the difference between being convinced and being intrigued. But you are intrigued (passive tense) because something or someone intrigues you (active tense). [See Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+intrigued%2Cintrigues+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: In support: The request for additional information clearly indicates that the listener is already intrigued (interested and curious) - he is soliciting more information. The intent is clearly to go about communicating that interest. "Convince me" is not the only option, or even the best option, but "Intrigue me" clearly does not communicate the intended message.

Comment: Or “Persuade me.” But I like “Please tell me more” best.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think talking about being "intrigue[d]" sufficiently indicates to the other person in the conversation that you're not convinced.

It is perfectly acceptable, and rather common, to simply state that you're not convinced.

If you did insist on using the word "intrigue" then you definitely wouldn't say "intrigue me"; it could confuse the other person as it's an unusual construction. Instead you would probably say "I'm intrigued", which, to be honest, is a closer approximation to "I am interested", and errs closer to suggesting that, actually, you are rather convinced.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could be more explicit with "make me intrigued", but after all it's a conversation, so "intrigue me" should be enough to convey your meaning.

Comment: Sorry, these are not phrases that a native speaker would use and it would sound odd to the listener.

Comment: @Kristina: It wouldn't be common, and we're clearly not helped by the fact that OP has misunderstood the word anyway, but it's not inherently odd, or incapable of being used naturally. *"I think talking to you would be really boring"*. *"You'd be wrong then - I'm actually a really interesting conversationalist"*. *"Go on then. **Intrigue me**."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that's the curse of choices.  With all other words at my disposal, I'd not go for "intrigue me".  I'd probably say, "sway me!" or "tickle my fancy!" or "persuade me!" or "lure me in!" or "win me over!"  but I think that I'm already intrigued, given the context of the question.

Comment: @ Kristina: haha. That poor "lonely heart" in my answer wouldn't have got a look-in if you'd been advertising in the same magazine!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't know. . . it did say she was wicked!  That's another word for "naughty", isn't it? lol!

Comment: I can imagine a native speaker saying "intrigue me" (although it's not a common expression). I cannot imagine a native speaker saying "make me intrigued".